# Durandal widget and custom culture files (globalization)

Tags: widget, globalization, culture, durandal, hottowel

I need to create a durandal widget that can support custom culture files for example `en-US.js` or `es-ES.js`, these files were in the path `durandal/widget/mywidget/cultures`:

The file en-US.js:

```
define(function () {
var messages = {
    name: 'Name',
    project: 'Project'
};

return messages;
```

});

file es-ES.js:

```
define(function () {
var messages = {
    name: 'Nombre',
    project: 'Proyecto'
};

return messages;
```

});

In the `controller.js` of widget:

```
var widget = require('durandal/widget');
var messages = require('durandal/widget/mywidget/cultures/'+ Globalize.cultureSelector);
```

But the variable `messages` with the path `'durandal/widget/mywidget/cultures/en-US'` for example doesn't work, variable `messages` is `undefined` and I don't use `messages.messages.name` or `messages.messages.project for example`.

I use Durandal 1.2.0

Please any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: How is `Globalize` defined in `controller.js`? Check if it's defined by setting a breakpoint at `var messages`. Once that's working it probably needs to be accessed via `messages.name` not `messages.messages...`

Comment: `Globalize` is defined out, and it work perfectly, for example `Globalize.cultureSelector` result `en-US`, the problem is `require('durandal/widget/mywidget/cultures/en-US')` result `undefined`. Maybe It is impossible add aditional files and folders under widget folder and reference them.

Comment: Looks like require can't access the file. Try to open file via browser (append .js). Check network tab for 404s and check upper/lowercase if running on a case-sensitive server.

Comment: I tried to load the file directly by the browser and It loaded fine, but in code require can't access the file.